# Переход с php на js, идеологическая сторона

Tags: php, javascript

Всем привет. Да, понимаю, что в названии примерно то же, что и сравнивать корову с баней, но я хочу понять именно идеологическую сторону. Вопросы напишу по порядку, заранее спасибо!

- Что касается сессий. На php сравнительно просто - при авторизации можно добавить в $_SESSION значение $_SESSION['user_id'] и вуаля, сессия в безопасности. Что делать на js? К примеру, есть сайт, нужно вывести кнопку со ссылкой на аккаунт пользователя, если человек залогинен и кнопку входа, если нет. На php реализовывалось легко - проверка $_SESSION['user_id'], затем вывод нужного блока, а как это сделать на JS? Понимаю, что можно при каждом обновлении страницы делать AJAX-запрос на backend о существовании пользователя, но где данные о пользователе хранить, чтобы они защищены были?
- Правильно ли я понимаю, что backend на node.js в разы производительнее, чем на php5.x?

P.S. вопросов оказалось немного, поскольку из ответов на эти вопросы уже буду понимать, куда дальше копать.

Comment: Насчет сессий в nodejs: https://github.com/expressjs/session

Comment: @Darth я немного неправильно составил вопрос, поэтому был неправильно понятым. Мне нужно хранить весь backend на php+mysql, а во фронт все выводит на vue.js, т.к. этот фреймворк мне показался очень перспективным, сейчас его изучаю. Или же чтобы сайт был интерфейсом back-end'а, все равно необходимо ставить ноду и на ноду уже делать упор?

Comment: Сессии живут исключительно на бекэнде. На фронте у вас от сессии только идентификатор (обычно кука)

Comment: Если общение с сервером идет AJAX'ом, то это никаких трудностей не составит в переходе с php на js? Т.е., к примеру, человек заполнил форму входа, ajax-запрос на правильность, вход, создание сессии. Как правильно это сделать? Т.е. хранить данные в $_SESSION для этого человека на php и при каждом запросе проверять равенство $_SESSION['user_id'] (Back-end) и $_COOKIES['user_id'] (Front-end)? Чет совсем эту тему не понимаю :(

Comment: Обычно это делается сервером автоматически, вам даже знать не нужно где и как лежит идентификатор сессии на фронтенде. Просто стартуете сессию, и используете её для идентификации. С точки зрения бекенда аякс запрос отличается от обычного только парой заголовков

Comment: @Darth понял. А если нужно взять ID данного пользователя и послать запрос, нужно в js коде писать <?php echo $_SESSION['user_id'];?>? Или же тут уже нужно использовать библиотеку, которую вы выше скинули?

Comment: @Darth немного поясню: к примеру, человек залогинился. Как вывести на front-end, залогинен он или нет, и, если залогинен, вывести его ник, ссылку на него и т.д.? Написать функцию на back-end'e, где проверять, есть у него $_SESSION['user_id'] или нет и возвращать это все в json, а из json уже на back-end выводить кнопку "регистрация/вход" или "Мой аккаунт"?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765175/how-to-get-session-variables-from-php-server-with-ajax-function-php-html-js-aj

Answer (score 1):

> немного поясню: к примеру, человек залогинился. Как вывести на
>   front-end, залогинен он или нет, и, если залогинен, вывести его ник,
>   ссылку на него и т.д.? Написать функцию на back-end'e, где проверять,
>   есть у него $_SESSION['user_id'] или нет и возвращать это все в json,
>   а из json уже на back-end выводить кнопку "регистрация/вход" или "Мой
>   аккаунт"

Пишешь на php контролер, который будет просто возвращать данные в JSON. Например проверяешь сессию, пользователь залогинен(присутствует $SESSION['user_id']) -> получаешь все нужные данные данные (ник, ссылку на него и т.д) -> пакуешь в JSON -> отправляешь его ответом -> в фрон энде распаковываешь данные и распихиваешь куда нужно. Либо же можно уже готовую разметку отделных блоков в JSON пихать и заменять их потом на клиенте. Если же в сессии ничего нет, просто отправляешь false.
пример:

```
/**
     * Получает данные о продукте из базы
     * 
     */
    Product.prototype.getData = function (page) {
        var self = this;
        var link = location.protocol + '//' + location.hostname + '/design/ajax/get_product_ajax.php';
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
        var body = 'id=' + encodeURIComponent(this.id) + '&' + 'page=' + encodeURIComponent(page);
        xhr.open("POST", link, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                self.data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            }
        }
        xhr.send(body);
    }
```

И контролер

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        if ($_POST['id']) {
            session_start();
            // логика......
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    }
```

Только такие манипуляции придется делать при переходе на любую страницу сайта.... Либо же первый раз запрос сделать, получить ответ и записать его допустим sessionStorage или LocalStorage, а уже оттуда брать инфу при переходе по страницам